# Using the 'for' loop in django tags for 'ForeignKey'

Tags: python, django, tags

My django loop in the templates does not work correctly. Why, because of me, everything looks good? 
Any help will be appreciated.

**My models.py**

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Person(models.Model):
    keywords = models.ForeignKey(Tags, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**My views.py**

```
def person_detail(request, user_id):
    person = get_object_or_404(Person, pk=user_id)
    context = {'person': person}
    return render(request, 'person_detail.html', context)
```

**My templates.html**

```
{% for tag in person.tags %}
<span class="badge badge-lg badge-pill badge-info"># {{ person.tags.name } </span>
{% endfor %}
```

This gives no results even though there is data in the database.

Comment: It doesn't matter @JohnGordon , it's not possible to loop over it, the `person.keywords` will just return an instance of `Tags`, you could use `ManyToManyField`, or you may use the `ForeignKey` field in Tags model instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it backwards. Your `Tags` model should have a foreign key to `Person`, not the other way around. For example:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...

class Tag(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Note that I've also renamed your `Tags` model to `Tag` as it makes sense to name models singular.

Then you can write the following:

```
{% for tag in person.tag_set.all %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Where can I find more information about something like 'tag_set.all'? 
I wonder if I can do the same in such an easy way, eg 1 tag added, or first added photo? something like '{% for tag in person.tag_set.first%}'